# AngularJS: How can I load ngGrid dynamically (on the fly)?

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I want to load ngGrid module dynamically. But it doesn't work.

I have added plunker also.. please check:
http://plnkr.co/edit/fFDQwX

so if i add 'ngGrid' in app.js file, in app module, it works file, but if i am doing same from demand.js on the fly, it wont work.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add ngGrid dependency in your module definition. Like this:

```
var dependencies =   ['ngRoute', 'loadOnDemand', 'ngGrid'];
var app = angular.module('app', dependencies);
```

Comment: That should be exactly what is missing